# How to make Jetty read new jetty-xxx.xml files

Tags: jetty

I have created a xml file with specific configuration for my jndi datasource, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
        <Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
            <New id="MyDB" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
                <Arg></Arg>
                <Arg>jdbc/MyDB</Arg>
                <Arg>
                    <New class="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
                        <Set name="url">******</Set>
                        <Set name="user">******</Set>
                        <Set name="password">******</Set>
                    </New>
                </Arg>
            </New>
        </Configure>
```

Dropped this file on $JETTY_BASE/etc but Jetty doesn't seem to be able to read the file to configure the datasource. However, if i pick the "New" tag and copy it to the jetty.xml file, it works.

I want this in a separate file so it makes easier for deploying to production and also to use this file in jetty-maven-plugin.

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty will only read what its been told to read based on the configuration.

You can see what that would be using the `--list-config` command line option.

Example:

```
[new-base]$ java -jar ../jetty-home-9.4.11.v20180605/start.jar --list-config

...(snip lots of output)...

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-threadpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-webapp.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-plus.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-annotations.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-jmx.xml
```

As you can see only the above XML files are read.

Lets say we add a `${jetty.base}/etc/my-datasource.xml`, we would also need to tell jetty to use that xml.

Manually we can add it to the `${jetty.base}/start.ini` or create a new file with any name you want such as `${jetty.base}/start.d/mydatasource.ini`.

Example:

```
[new-base]$ cat start.d/mydatasource.ini
etc/mydatasource.xml
```

Now when you ask, you'll see it listed ...

```
[new-base]$ java -jar ../jetty-home-9.4.11.v20180605/start.jar --list-config


...(snip lots of output)...

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-threadpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-webapp.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-plus.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-annotations.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-jmx.xml
 ${jetty.base}/etc/mydatasource.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work perfectly. Just by creating the new ini file inside the start.d folder was enough. This way I can leave the original jetty files unchanged and just add new files in order to configure my production server.

Comment: Thank you. This isn't discussed clearly anywhere in the Jetty documentation and it's very critical to understand.

Comment: @user2959589 see https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html